# How to use spread as argument of function

Tags: typescript

I`m want to give canvas.context.fillRect some argument by spread,and tslint tell me this function need 4 argument but get 1,how to fix the error?or Is this my mistake?

```
    public drawRect(option: RectOption | number[]): CanvasRenderingContext2D {
        let Option: any;
        if (option.constructor === Object) {
            Option = option as RectOption;
            this.ctx.fillRect(Option.x, Option.y, Option.w, Option.h);
        } else {
            Option = option;
            if (Option.length === 4) {
                console.log(Option)
                this.ctx.fillRect(...Option);
            }
        }
        return this.ctx;
    }
    drawRect([325,100,200,200])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[lib.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L3152) declares `fillRect` as `fillRect(x: number, y: number, w: number, h: number): void;`, which is more accurate than `fillRect(rect: number[]);` . If I was you, I'd choose to explicitly pass four numbers to that function, which makes code more semantics:

```
this.ctx.fillRect(Option[0], Option[1], Option[2], Option[3]);
```

or

```
this.ctx.fillRect(...Option as [number, number, number, number]);
```

Anyway, you need to tell TypeScript compiler that Option is a 4-length array of numbers, which could not inferred from `if(Option.length === 4)` or `if(Option.length === 2+2)`.

By the way, `any` is always ok(would not cause compile errors), but strongly not recomended.